# Dictionary getting allocated every time

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have two views. In class one I have table with custom cell, where am re-using the cell for three times. I wanted to update table cell text of each row with selected text from another class. I have implemented `protocol` to take the text value from another class and updating. For storing each row value am using `NSDictionary`. So that I can take the dictionary value and update in my `cellforrowatindexpath` to update cell text value. My code,

Class A - Objective C :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"challengeTableCell";
    cell = (EnrollmentChallengeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[EnrollmentChallengeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.answerTextfield.delegate = self;

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.questionTitleLabel.text = @"Challenge Question 1";
    cell.questionLabel.tag = 100;
    cell.questionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSString *user1 = [myDict objectForKey:@"firstQuestion"];
    NSLog(@"firstquestion: %@",user1);
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.questionTitleLabel.text = @"Challenge Question 2";
    cell.questionLabel.tag = 101;
    NSString *user2 = [myDict objectForKey:@"secondQuestion"];
    NSLog(@"secondQuestion: %@",user2);

}
else {
    cell.questionTitleLabel.text = @"Challenge Question 3";
    cell.questionLabel.tag = 102;
    NSString *user3 = [myDict objectForKey:@"thirdQuestion"];
    NSLog(@"thirdQuestion: %@",user3);
}

if (cell.questionLabel.tag == 100 || cell.questionLabel.tag == 101 || cell.questionLabel.tag == 102) {
    UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectQuestion:)];
    [cell.questionLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.questionLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

    return cell;
}

-(void)selectQuestion:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:challengeQuestionsTable];
    newIndexPath = [challengeQuestionsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation];
    selectQuestionVC = [EnrollmentSelectQuestionViewController instantiate];
    selectQuestionVC.questionDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:selectQuestionVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Table Selection Delegate

-(void)valueChanged:(NSString *)questionString {
    //[challengeQuestionsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    passedValue = questionString;
    NSLog(@"questionvalue: %@",passedValue);
    NSLog(@"mydict: %lu",(unsigned long)[myDict count]);
    cell = [challengeQuestionsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    NSLog(@"you have selected index: %ld", (long)newIndexPath.row);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newIndexPath.row forKey:@"SelectedIndex"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //    NSInteger numberOfRows = [challengeQuestionsTable numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    NSLog(@"indexpath row: %ld",newIndexPath.row);

    if (newIndexPath.row == 0) {
        [myDict setValue:passedValue forKey:@"firstQuestion"];
    } else if (newIndexPath.row == 1) {
        [myDict setValue:passedValue forKey:@"secondQuestion"];
    } else {
        [myDict setValue:passedValue forKey:@"thirdQuestion"];
  }

  NSLog(@"mydict: %@",myDict);
  NSLog(@"1st: %@",[myDict objectForKey:@"firstQuestion"]);
  NSLog(@"2nd: %@",[myDict objectForKey:@"secondQuestion"]);
  NSLog(@"3rd: %@",[myDict objectForKey:@"thirdQuestion"]);
}
```

Class B - Swift:

```
var questionDelegate: SelectedQuestionDelegate?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("selected index :",indexPath.row)

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    print("did select and the text is \(selectedCell?.textLabel?.text)")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EnrollmentChallengeQuestions", bundle: nil)
    challengeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChallengeQuestions") as! EnrollmentChallengeQuestionsViewController
    challengeVC.passedValue = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text
    print("text label value: ", challengeVC.passedValue)
    questionDelegate?.valueChanged(challengeVC.passedValue)
    self.present(challengeVC, animated: true , completion: nil)
}
```

Here in `ValueChanged` function, My dictionary is holding only one value at a time. I want to hold the first question for first row, second question for second row and for third also simultaneously. My dictionary is getting refreshed each time. Also tried to alloc my dict in `viewdidload` & `viewwillappear`. All methods getting called again while coming from another class. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: what is the navigation between your two controllers?
Which of your two controllers hold the answer and which contains the answers?
Why do you mix Swift and Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of `self.present(challengeVC, animated: true , completion: nil)`.

Currently when you select a question , you present the challengeVC, again so its `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods are being called again, hence your dictionary is being allocated again